# 3d camera transformation effects on 2d image pixel

Tags: c++, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, pixel

I have a question.Lets say i captured a image from camera.after that i rotate my camera to rX,rY,rZ( pitch , Yaw , Roll ) and translate it to ( Tx , Ty , Tz ) and capture second image .Now where will a image pixel point(Px,Py) in first image will be in second image ?

```
Px,Py ( any pixel point in image - given )
rX,rY,rZ , Tx , Ty , Tz (camera rotation and translation vectors - given)
have to find new value of that pixel point after camera rotation.
```

Any equation or logic to solve this problem ? it may be easier but i couldn't find the solution.please help me.

thanks.

Comment: It depends on the distance beteeen the camera and the object it captures.

Comment: okk lets assume that the distance is known. let d is the distance between firstly captured image's specific pixel and the camera. and also all the focal length etc intrinsic parameters are also known.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you don't have enough information to solve the problem. Let's see if I can make a drawing here to show you why:

```
      /
cam1 <    (1)   (2)   (3)
      \


                \ /
                 v
                cam2
```

I hope this is clear. Let's say you take three pictures from `cam1`, with some object located at `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`. In all three cases the object is located exactly in the center of the picture.

Now you move the camera to the `cam2` location, which involves a 90 degree counter clockwise rotation on Y plus some translation on X and Z.

For simplicity, let's say your `Px,Py` is the center of the picture. The three pictures that you took with `cam1` have the same object at that pixel, so whatever equations and calculations you come up with to locate that pixel in the `cam2` pictures, they will have the same input for the three pictures, so they will also produce the same output. But clearly, that will be wrong, since from the `cam2` location each of the three pictures that you take will see the object in a very different position, moving horizontally across the frame.

Do you see what's missing?

If you wanted to do this properly, you would need your `cam1` device to also capture a [depth map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map), so that for each pixel you also know how far away from the camera the object represented by it was. This is what will differentiate the three pictures where the object moves farther away from the camera.

If you had the depth for `Px,Py`, then you can then do an inverse perspective projection from `cam1` and obtain the 3D location of that pixel relative to `cam1`. You will then apply the inverse rotation and translation to convert the point to the 3D space relative to `cam2`, and then do a [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) from `cam2` to find what will be the new pixel location.

Sorry for the bad news, I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Miguel , for a great explanation. i appreciate. btw , if u dont know depth how augmented reality etc works without use of kinect.sorry if the que. is not related.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but typically AR applications work by doing some sort of pattern recognition of markers on the video stream, so that CGI components can be aligned to it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on [Epipolar Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry). Without knowing anything else than image coordinates, your corresponding pixel could be anywhere along a line in the second image.

Comment: Read through the link I provided. If you're interested in such problems in general, I would refer you to the book "Multiple View Geometry" by Hartley and Zisserman.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `opengl transformation math`. The links should provide you the math behind rotation and translation in 3d.

For example, [this link](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=opengl%20translate%20rotate%20math&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~psilord/docs/local_axis.html&ei=jJWtTpGvFNHKswbB35HnDw&usg=AFQjCNHKybE8ozyPnhRD6HaLRaK5xUC9VA&cad=rja) shows :

```
 Rotations:
  Rotation about the X axis by an angle a:
  |1       0        0    0|
  |0  cos(a)  -sin(a)    0|
  |0  sin(a)   cos(a)    0|
  |0       0        0    1|
```